# npm: using scripts versus writing a plain node script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I'm working on migrating an existing workflow I wrote which uses Gulp + Webpack.

Continuing to use Gulp seems redundant. As time went by all it did was run Webpack.

I decided I'll just use npm's scripts to manage the workflow, but a question popped into my head and I can't answer it myself.

Why should one use npm scripts over a single script file written in a node manner?

Why use this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test **.js",
    "lint": "lint",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean", // <-- hurts my eyes
    "build": "webpack --bla bla --some more bla",
    "minify": "npm run build"
  }
```

Over this ( even the clean is redundant imo ):

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "./scripts/clean.js", // <-- I get full control on clean operation. 
    "build": "./scripts/webpack.js", // <-- pre & post operation are invoked when I want them to
  }
```

The former approach gets messy real quick, passing arguments / doing programmatic operation is a pain. For example, controlling the failing strategy,  using custom loggers or debugging seems like an impossible feat.